# Jquery UI slider options object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am attempting to use the jQuery UI slider in a project. I have a need to create sliders with different options and I am attempting to use the `option` method.

I have done the following:

### HTML

```
<div class="slider" data-a-orientation="vertical"></div>
```

I am placing the slider options as data attributes in HTML and then retrieving them with jQuery

### JS

```
init : function(element)
        {
            this.elem = element;
            this.$elem = $(element);
            // target element
            this.slider_target = this.$elem.find('.slider');
        
        /*
         * Get all the data-attr from the .slider target element    
         * if there is any
         * loop over all and create an object of options. Note all our data attr 
         * are -a- separated. 
         */
        var slider_opt_obj = {};
        $.each(this.slider_target.data(), function(key, val){
            // note ! ~ each of the data attributes are : data-a-attribute_title 
            // we need to remove a .. the - character is already removed
            // this was added to stop any overwriting by the jQuery ui plugin
            var key_lwr = key.toLowerCase();
            slider_opt_obj[key_lwr.slice(1)] = val;
        });
        
        // create the sliders
        this.sliderCreate( this.slider_target, slider_opt_obj);
    },
    sliderCreate : function(target, options)
    {
        var self = this;
        
        if( !self.objectEmpty(options) ) {
            // does not work throws error
            target.slider("option", options);
        } else  {
            // no options
            target.slider();
        }
    }
```

This line

```
target.slider("option", options);
```

is causing the following error

```
Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
```

According to the [jQuery ui docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option) the method `option` does accept a object .. what am I missing here ?

Also [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqp7K/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call .slider("option", options) before the slider is created. Just create the slider with your options object as the parameter:

```
target.slider(options);
```